# django-rest-auth unable to access user details page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using django-rest-auth to authenticate and register my user I can do everyhting.

Login is working Registration is working but I am unable to access get User details:

```
/rest-auth/user/ (GET, PUT, PATCH)
```

I am trying to access this endpoint I am using JWT I am getting correct token. But when I am using this command in curl:

```
 curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer <jwt-toke>'
```

I am getting this error:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

What do I need to do to access details of user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long investigation, I was able to find a solution and according to the documentation if you want to use JWT in django-rest-auth.

They shared one link which is not working actual link is:

```
https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/
```

After installing django-rest-auth.

You need to install django-rest-framework-jwt using:

```
pip install djangorestframework-jwt
```

And it will work fine if you want to access this URL:

```
/rest-auth/user/ (GET, PUT, PATCH)
```

You need to pass JWT instead of Bearer example:

```
 curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/ -H 'Authorization: JWT <jwt-toke>'
```

And it worked for me.